# Ruby regex matching of selective tweets

Tags: ruby, regex, twitter

Im having difficulty using .match to only allow and block selective tweets and display only those from 'does_match?'

```
  def does_match?
    allow = "/orange|grape\sfruit|apple/"
    block = "/@fruits|coconut/"
    allowfruits = "/berry|mango/"

    @tweet.match(allow).nil?
    @tweet.match(block)
    @tweet.match(allowfruits) if @user =~ /\A(twitteruser|anotheraccount)\Z/
    @tweet.match(/@[A-Za-z0-9_:-]+/)
    return @tweet
  end

  def show
    return @tweet
  end
```

Comment: What problems are you having? What does your data input/output look like?

Comment: at the moment it appears that the output is the same as the input

Answer (score 0):

firstly, You are defining Your regexps as a strings
do this instead

```
allow = /orange|grape\sfruit|apple/
```

secondly, You're doing some matches bot doing nothing with its return values
do this

```
if @tweet.match(allow)
   # rest of logic
   # checking blocked and allowed for user
   @tweet # or true
else
   nil # or false
end
```